# Reading File of Complex Numbers

Tags: import, complex

I have a text file "IQ256.txt" with the following format (one complex pair per line):

```
-23636.100 13359.055I  
-25478.040 9342.004I  
-26637.370 5257.033I  
-27184.020 1087.021I  
-27069.778 -2976.033I  
-26338.223 -6446.660I
```

which I want to import into Mathematica for spectral analysis. I'm having trouble doing this. Can someone help this newbie?

Answer (score 2):

This interpreter works `DelimitedSequence["ComplexNumber"]`, you can use it with `SemanticImport`:

```
SemanticImport["IQ256.txt", DelimitedSequence["ComplexNumber"]]
```

Or interpret the string directly:

```
Interpreter[DelimitedSequence["ComplexNumber"]] @ Import["IQ256.txt"]
```

Answer (score 1):

E.g:

```
Total[ToExpression[Import["asd.txt", "Data"]], {2}]
```

Comment: Thanks! That works!